# Bash readline not working inside a while loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, scripting, do-while

I have tried with this one day but still i cant figure out why?
echo is working fine but if is always return false.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
   scan_fileExists(){
        while read file; do
            echo $file #echo is working
            if [ -f $file ]; then
                echo "Yes"
            fi
        done < $1
   }
   scan_fileExists "/home/myfile"
```

Comment: /home/myfile is simple file with 3 text lines

Comment: I guess your problem is that "Yes" is not getting printed at all? What are the 3 text lines in /home/myfile? are they filenames?

Comment: `if [ -f "$file" ]; then` ... (Note the quotes..) Also, are you sure these files exist?

Comment: Yes AMD you're correct, its not getting printed at all rather than i hard code the file path instead of use $file; yes /home/myfile inclusing file names

Comment: I have tried both  with and without quotes,yes files are exists;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e                               # modified
   scan_fileExists(){
        x=$'\r'                              # added
        while read file; do
            echo $file #echo is working
            if [ -f ${file%${x}*} ]; then    # modified
                echo "Yes"
            fi
        done < $1
   }
   scan_fileExists "/home/myfile"
```

Other method to keep `sh` as shell (disadvantage: while runs as member of a pipe in a subshell):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
   scan_fileExists(){
        tr -d "\r" < $1 | while read file; do  # modified
            echo $file #echo is working
            if [ -f $file ]; then
                echo "Yes"
            fi
        done                                   # modified
   }
   scan_fileExists "/home/myfile"
```

Comment: Yes its working perfectly, could you please describe whats the wrong with my snippet and what is the logic behind your script any way superb and thank you very much

Comment: Your `/home/myfile` contains at end of each line an additional disturbing carriage return (hex 0d). Unix/Linux uses only a newline (hex 0a) to mark end of line, Windows uses newline and carriage return.